# Unable to pare the href tag in python

Tags: beautifulsoup

I get the following output in my beautiful soup. 
[Search over [301,944 datasets](/metrics)\n]

I need to extract only the number 301,944 in this. Please guide me how this can be done. My code so far

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source = requests.get('https://www.data.gov/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup (source , 'lxml')
#print soup.prettify()
images = soup.find_all('small')
print images
con = images.find_all('a') // I am unable to get anchor tag here. It says anchor tag not present
print con
#for con in images.find_all('a',href=True):
    #print con
#content = images.split('metrics')
#print content[1]
#images = soup.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('\d+')})
#print images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `<small>` tag on website.

Your `images` variable references it. But you use it in a wrong way to retrive anchor tag.

If you want to retrieve text from `a` tag you can get it with:

> soup.find('small').a.text

where `find` method returns first small element it encounters on website. If you use `find_all`, you will get list of all `small` elements (but there's only one small tag here).

Comment: its not working. When I do that it reports "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\vishwa\myscripts\value_site.py", line 7, in <module>
    images = soup.find_all('small').a.text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. " % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'a'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: I did it on my pc, it just showed text from anchor tag. I used `find_all()` but since its only anchor tag in small tag, I used find() to retrieve just that one.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it.